# Error when trying to pull row based on index value in the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'am reading a data off a csv file. The columns are as below:

Date    , Buy, Sell, Price

1/10/2011, 1 , 5,    500

1/15/2011, 4,  2,    500

When I tried to pull data based on index like df["2011-01-10"], I got an error KeyError: '2011-01-10'

Anyone know what this is might be the case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are passing your argument is wrong, try passing it in the same pattern as its in csv. Like ["1/10/2011"], it should work. Good luck :)